# JSON.parse unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data

Tags: json, fetch

```
function fetchAPI4(){

return fetch("https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/123456798hfd347gd57g5789gfdsxgxxxxx/logs/received?start=2021-05-09T00:00:00Z&end=2021-05-09T01:00:00Z&&count=10&fields=ClientRequestBytes,EdgeColoCode", {
  headers: {
   "Authorization": "Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "X-Auth-Email": "xxx@xxx.com"
  }
})
}
```

it is giving me the output in the wrong json format how should i correct it??
the output i am getting is following

{
"ClientRequestBytes": 1111,
"EdgeColoCode": "aav"
}

{
"ClientRequestBytes": 2222,
"EdgeColoCode": "bca"
}

{
"ClientRequestBytes": 3333,
"EdgeColoCode": "ffx"
}

the above is wrong json format with wide space and showing me

**JSON.parse unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data**

How should i correct it??
below i was trying but it didnot work

```
let response4 = await fetchAPI4()
         response4  = JSON.parse('['+response4+']')                
               let json4 = await response4.json()
        json4 = json4.replace(/\\n/g, '');
```

Comment: The "output" you show is not JSON. That text would need to be inside an array and have `,` between them. Best thing would be to fix the API if you can, otherwise ask the owner of the API how the data should be consumed.

Comment: there is no way to convert my output in Json format?? @crashmstr

Comment: [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) is a very specific string format. However you get the data, it needs to be in that format for parsing. If your data is truly objects clumped together without commas separating them and without a top level object or array containing them, it is not JSON *at that level* and either is doing something other than JSON or is poorly designed. You would need to find the lines that are hopefully JSON, pull them out, and `JSON.parse` them individually.